# Influence of order in which meshes are added to the scene despite sortObjects enabled

Tags: three.js, 3d, rendering, transparency

I was wondering: what are the effects of the order, in which (transparent) meshes are added to a scene? I know that if `renderer.sortObjects` is set to false, this will be the rendering-order. But what effects does it have when left at true?
I noticed that in r124 this can cause different results for a transparent mesh inside a transparent mesh.

Below is twice the same scene, once with the **dark** blue mesh added first (left) and once with the **light** blue mesh added first (right). Why does this happen?

Edit: I found that using the `renderOrder` property the behaviour can be overwritten, but still be reproduced - so it seems the influence of the order in which meshes are added to the scene is simply that it defines the rendering order, unless the rendering order is explicitly specified.

So with this, the question arises: how does `sortObjects` work? Isn't it supposed to ensure consistent rendering based on the distance of the objects to the camera?

[image: dark-blue first]
[image: light-blue first]

Comment: For the objects having `material.transparent` set to `true`, try setting `material.depthWrite` to `false`.

Comment: that doesn't do anything in this case.. however `renderOrder`was helpful, see edit.